# How does the fact that a function is pair(or impair) help to find it's expression in power series?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Suppose I have a function that I want to express in power series. I study its parity, how will that help me to find its expression in power series.

I know that the usual function such as $\cos(x)$ are pair, thus if we develop them into an usual expression $\sum a_nx^n$, for all odd $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n =0$, but I still need to find what the $a_n$ is equal to, and the parity doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: What are the properties of pair (or impair) functions?

Comment: Use the terms "even" and "odd".

Answer (score 1):

An even function (not *pair*, which seems to be the spanish term...) cannot have non-zero coefficients for **odd** powers of $\;x\;$ , and the opposite for odd functions.